# Orphan blank window randomly pops up

Tags: macos, monterey

Since about a week ago, I've had a window like this one[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrPbg.png) popping up out of nowhere a few times a day.

It's not "attached" to any app, in the sense that it's not coming to the foreground while using the app switcher. Selecting it doesn't show a corresponding app name in the menu bar either.

I closed all my apps, then all the menu bar apps, then I opened Activity Monitor, selected everything and then "Quit" and it was still there.

If I close the window, sometimes a new one pops up; sometimes it just goes away and doesn't seem to come back for a while.

Is there a way to find the process that corresponds to a particular window like that?

```
  System Version:   macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
  Model Name:   MacBook Air
  Model Identifier: MacBookAir10,1
  Chip: Apple M1
  Total Number of Cores:    8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
  Memory:   16 GB
  System Firmware Version:  7429.41.5
  OS Loader Version:    7429.41.5
```

[image: Screenshot of a blank window on a colorful background]

Comment: First look in monitor app. When it happens, it should be the process with the biggest id. Do you have some device connected to you Mac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [duplicate on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/902869/how-to-identify-which-process-is-running-which-window-in-mac-os-x) explaining your options. These basically are:

- Use the Accessibility Inspector from Xcode. It can show you the app name (you need to enlarge the Accessibility Inspector window or scroll and open the `Hierarchy` section; the top entry is the app).
- Use the [`lswin.py` script](https://superuser.com/a/1008520/79518). See the comment on that answer for a Python3 solution.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I hadn't heard of the Accessibility Inspector before and that solved it. I restarted my computer, the window popped up again and I was able to identify some VTech software that I uninstalled. It's surprising that it didn't seem to show up in Activity Monitor, but that will do for now. Thanks again!